# Convert Guava predicate to Java 8 predicate

Tags: java, java-8, guava, predicate

I am trying to convert the below code to java predicate from Gauva predicate but don't know how to apply or,and not function of java predicate to the below method

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;
class Test {

private Predicate<String> getPath() {
      
        return or(

               
                PathSelectors.ant("/v1/*/s1/**"),
                PathSelectors.ant("/v1/*/s2/**"),
                and(PathSelectors.ant("/v/*/test/*/s3/*")),
                not(PathSelectors.ant("/v1/*/test/*/s4/*"))),
                PathSelectors.ant("/v1/*/test/*/s5/*/*"),
                PathSelectors.ant("/v1/*/test/*/s5/*/*"),
               
        );
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Your brackets are misplaced, `/v1/*/test/*/s5/*/*` appears twice, and negating `/v1/*/test/*/s4/*` is pointless, as none of the specified patterns would include that pattern anyway. It’s like saying “A but not B”. Generally, using `/v1/*/s[12]/**` would be simpler and more efficient than combining `/v1/*/s1/**` and `/v1/*/s2/**` with `or`.

Answer (score 1):

`Predicate` has `and`, `or` and a `negate` method, but and and or only accept a single other predicate. Still you can use these methods like this:

```java
PathSelectors.ant("/v1/*/s1/**")
     .or(PathSelectors.ant("/v1/*/s2/**")
    .or(PathSelectors.ant("/v/*/test/*/s3/*").and(PathSelectors.ant("/v1/*/test/*/s4/*").negate()))
    .or(PathSelectors.ant("/v1/*/test/*/s5/*/*")
    .or(PathSelectors.ant("/v1/*/test/*/s5/*/*");
```